# Is ODBC on Windows 2003 slower than on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, sql-server-2005, odbc

I am seeing some MSSQL 2005 performance issues, and I am trying to diagnose the cause. I am using SQL Profiler to gather query execution times. Both the client app (using ODBC), and the SQL server are running on Windows 2003. I am also using Windows 7 (client) with a different Windows 2003 server to compare results.

#### Windows 7 client / Windows 2003 server:

- SQL management studio: 393ms
- Through ODBC: 215ms

#### Windows 2003 client:

- SQL management studio: approx 155ms
- Through ODBC: 3145ms

... in both cases, I'm running SQL Management Studio on the client. To me, these figures suggest there's something wrong with the ODBC client on the Windows 2003 server.

On Windows, I see that the ODBC "SQL Server" driver is version `6.01.7600.16385` but on Windows 2003, it is `2000.86.3959.00` (by default). Could this be the problem? Is it possible to update an ODBC driver?

Comment: It seems to me that your test is skewed. You're using two different servers, so how do you know that the server isn't the problem? My suggestion would be to test against the same server and compare the results.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yeah you're right. I re-created the test on another Windows 2003 server and client combo, and did not see the same slow results. I guess the answer to my question is "no; it should be the same"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer is no; it performs just the same.